# PHP remote_addr doesn't work iOS with VPN

Tags: php, ios, ip, vpn

I am using the VPN on iOS phone. But when I open my web page I didn't get VPN IP. The PHP show my real IP on the page.

I get an IP address with this code block ;

```
<?php

die($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is showing your server IP instead of visitor IP. This is a bug caused by misconfiguration of the web server or some sort of proxy on the way. The mystery might be solved if you find out who's IP it is :) Try

```
  $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
        $ipAddress = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you are using VPN , there  is no PHP script that can know if you are behind VPN . That mean you can't get the Vpn ip .